Getting MSB3073 error while building app on Windows 11
I was working on this flutter app but now it is throwing the following error, however, this wasn't the case before:
C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Hacktoberfest\bookie\windows\flutter\ephemeral\flutter_windows.dll.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib      
gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST
/MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed
/manifestinput:C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Hacktoberfest\bookie\windows\runner\runner.exe.manifest /DEBUG
/PDB:"C:/Users/lenovo/Documents/Hacktoberfest/bookie/build/windows/x64/runner/Debug/bookie.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /TLBID:1   
/DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"C:/Users/lenovo/Documents/Hacktoberfest/bookie/build/windows/x64/runner/Debug/bookie.lib"     
/MACHINE:X64  /machine:x64 bookie.dir\Debug\Runner.res
[   +4 ms]   bookie.dir\Debug\flutter_window.obj
[        ]   bookie.dir\Debug\main.obj
[        ]   bookie.dir\Debug\utils.obj
[        ]   bookie.dir\Debug\win32_window.obj
[        ]   bookie.dir\Debug\generated_plugin_registrant.obj
[ +521 ms]   bookie.vcxproj -> C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Hacktoberfest\bookie\build\windows\x64\runner\Debug\bookie.exe
[  +27 ms] FinalizeBuildStatus:
[   +1 ms]   Deleting file "bookie.dir\Debug\bookie.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
[   +1 ms]   Touching "bookie.dir\Debug\bookie.tlog\bookie.lastbuildstate".
[   +1 ms] Done Building Project "C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Hacktoberfest\bookie\build\windows\x64\runner\bookie.vcxproj"     
(default targets).
[  +23 ms] InitializeBuildStatus:
[   +1 ms]   Creating "x64\Debug\ALL_BUILD\ALL_BUILD.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
[  +17 ms] CustomBuild:
[   +1 ms]   All outputs are up-to-date.
[  +25 ms] FinalizeBuildStatus:
[   +1 ms]   Deleting file "x64\Debug\ALL_BUILD\ALL_BUILD.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
[   +1 ms]   Touching "x64\Debug\ALL_BUILD\ALL_BUILD.tlog\ALL_BUILD.lastbuildstate".
[   +1 ms] Done Building Project "C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Hacktoberfest\bookie\build\windows\x64\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default
targets).
[  +14 ms] InitializeBuildStatus:
[   +1 ms]   Touching "x64\Debug\INSTALL\INSTALL.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
[ +166 ms] PostBuildEvent:
[        ]   setlocal
[        ]   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Debug -P
cmake_install.cmake
[   +1 ms]   if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
[        ]   :cmEnd
[        ]   endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
[        ]   :cmErrorLevel
[        ]   exit /b %1
[   +1 ms]   :cmDone
[   +1 ms]   if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
[   +1 ms]   :VCEnd
[ +131 ms]   -- Install configuration: "Debug"
[  +65 ms]   CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:75 (file):
[        ]     file cannot create directory: C:/Program Files/bookie.  Maybe need
[        ]     administrative privileges.
[  +41 ms] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: The command "setlocal     
[C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Hacktoberfest\bookie\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[  +23 ms] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: "C:\Program Files
(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"
-DBUILD_TYPE=Debug -P cmake_install.cmake [C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Hacktoberfest\bookie\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]  
[   +3 ms] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto
:cmEnd [C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Hacktoberfest\bookie\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[   +3 ms] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd
[C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Hacktoberfest\bookie\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[   +3 ms] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call
:cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone [C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Hacktoberfest\bookie\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]  
[   +2 ms] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel
[C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Hacktoberfest\bookie\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[   +1 ms] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1
[C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Hacktoberfest\bookie\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[   +2 ms] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone
[C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Hacktoberfest\bookie\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[   +2 ms] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto
:VCEnd [C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Hacktoberfest\bookie\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[   +2 ms] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code  
1. [C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Hacktoberfest\bookie\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[   +1 ms] Done Building Project "C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Hacktoberfest\bookie\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj" (default  
targets) -- FAILED.
[   +1 ms] Build FAILED.
[   +4 ms] "C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Hacktoberfest\bookie\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
[   +1 ms] (PostBuildEvent target) ->
[   +1 ms]   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: The command "setlocal     
[C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Hacktoberfest\bookie\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[   +1 ms] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: "C:\Program Files
(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"
-DBUILD_TYPE=Debug -P cmake_install.cmake [C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Hacktoberfest\bookie\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]  
[   +2 ms] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto
:cmEnd [C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Hacktoberfest\bookie\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[   +2 ms] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd
[C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Hacktoberfest\bookie\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[   +2 ms] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call
:cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone [C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Hacktoberfest\bookie\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]  
[   +2 ms] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel
[C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Hacktoberfest\bookie\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[   +2 ms] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1
[C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Hacktoberfest\bookie\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[   +1 ms] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone
[C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Hacktoberfest\bookie\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[   +2 ms] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto
:VCEnd [C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Hacktoberfest\bookie\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[   +2 ms] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code  
1. [C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Hacktoberfest\bookie\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[   +1 ms]     0 Warning(s)
[        ]     1 Error(s)
[        ] Time Elapsed 00:00:51.79
[ +135 ms] Building Windows application... (completed in 70.0s)
[   +3 ms] Error: Build process failed.
[   +8 ms] "flutter run" took 78,099ms.
[  +45 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:815:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1389:27)     
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
           (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:355:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:295:5)       
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:119:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>


[ +267 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 256ms
[   +1 ms] Running 1 shutdown hook
[   +6 ms] Shutdown hooks complete
[   +1 ms] exiting with code 1
PS C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Hacktoberfest\bookie> 

I don't understand why suddenly it start requiring privileged access.
I ran flutter run -v --dart-define-from-file=.env to run the flutter app on windows but I am getting this error here.
I also saw other posts where they I have to run it in a privileged mode. But, this shouldn't be happening, right?

It attempts to install (-- Install configuration: "Debug") a software into C:/Program Files. Changing content of this directory definitely requires administrative privileges.

But, why does it change the file suddenly? I was simply trying to run. It ran good before that.

I know nothing about your flutter application, so I don't know why it is decided to be installed. Knowing that "it worked before" may help your to debug the problem, but for other this knowledge is of little value.
